# ROS gmapping laser scan wrong range problem

Tags: ros, slam

I found the requirement of laser scan is,

-pi to pi, positive step, and 0 degree is the car's moving forward direction. i.e.

```
angle_min= -135 * (pi/180); //angle correspond to FIRST beam in scan ( in rad)
angle_max= 135 * (pi/180); //angle correspond to LAST beam in scan ( in rad)
angle_increment =0.25 * (pi/180); // Angular resolution i.e angle between 2 beams
```

https://answers.ros.org/question/198843/need-explanation-on-sensor_msgslaserscanmsg/

now my lidar is 0 to 180 degree. negative step, and 90 degree is the car's moving forward direction.

```
angle_min= 0; 
angle_max=  (pi/180); 
angle_increment = -0.25 * (pi/180);
```

and it did not work!

I scanned a map. Then I used AMCL to locate the robot.

Even the laser scan are matched in below pic. But the direction is wrong. the yellow arrow is correct one, the red arrow was wrongly estimated by AMCL.

How can I resolve this direction conflict?

thank you.

[image]

Comment: Without going very deep analyzing your problem, I would say, just rotate your lidar frame in your URDF (or where ever the lidar frame is defined) by 90 degrees. Have you tried that? If you want a "correct" answer to your question you should post a link to your lidar datasheet. I think it is standard to have forward being 0 degrees.

Comment: sorry, my problem is a simulation problem for course project, i cannot rotate the lidar frame. my assumption is that I can use some TF to fix it, but one more question, is it more common that the positive x-axis is the forward direction? also AMCL and movebase assumed positive x-axis the forward direction too? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the scan angles incorrectly

```
angle_min= 0; 
angle_max= pi; 
angle_increment = 0.25 * (pi/180);
```

---

For your robot base to laser tf, laser scan rays must match like below

```
 angle of ray 0   = 0                                     // positive y-axis of robot base
 angle of ray 1   = angle_min + (angle_increment) * 1
 angle of ray 2   = angle_min + (angle_increment) * 2
 .
 .
 angle of ray 360 = angle_min + (angle_increment) * 360 // positive x-axis of robot base
 .
 .
 angle of ray 720 = angle_min + (angle_increment) * 720 // negative y-axis of robot base
```

Comment: so positive y-axis is -90 degree, negative y-axis is +90 degree, positive x-axis is 0 degree? but in https://answers.ros.org/question/198843/need-explanation-on-sensor_msgslaserscanmsg/, it mentioned for, hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 laser scanner , the positive y-axis is +90 degree? so it was incorrect by default?

Comment: the link you are referring is showing laser frame and laser frame and base frame differ only in translation. You can choose laser frame as your wish and you have to provide correct tf between the laser frame and robot base frame.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need explicitly matching moving direction with Rviz, but from what I can see on the screenshot **TF** node is used. It might affect your robot base frame orientation. You can experiment with its parameters, so you will be able to rotate your robot base frame as @MRFalcon mentioned. [Here is a couple of tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials), should be enough to solve your problem.